# Botium - Handle inputs from adaptive cards

Tags: chatbot, botium-box

I am trying to test the adaptive cards to generate a button click. I have a "Status" button in the adaptive card.

I tried the convo provided in the following sample

https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-directline3/blob/master/samples/convo/spec/convo/adaptive.convo.txt

When I use the following convo
#me 
BUTTON card Status

botium seem to ignore card and sends "card Status" as a text

[image: botium adaptive cards testing]

Is this something to do with the directline connector ? how can i test the adaptive card inputs ?

Answer (score 0):

"card" is not a magic word there. It could be (yes newline where missing):

```
#me 
BUTTON Hello World!
```

How the buttons are handled, depends on your backend, you have to [setup Botium](https://github.com/codeforequity-at/botium-connector-directline3#directline3_button_type-and-directline3_button_value_field) correspondingly. You can read about it [here](https://botium.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/BOTIUM/pages/63209497/How+Can+I+Simulate+Buttons+with+my+Azure+Bot).